# Can I specify a separate "screen" and "print" view for a report in MS Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services, printing

I guess this is not quite a "programming" question, but it is bothering me none the less.  I am the author of a fairly complicated report with a lot of drill-downs and dynamically displayed elements.

The business users I'm writing the report for like the drill-downs on the screen, but when they print, they want to see the report completely expanded and have all information displayed for when they take the report into meetings and such.

Is there an (easy) way for me to tell Reporting Services "When displaying on the screen, do this, when you print, do this?"  I would think that MS would have thought of an option like that, but I can't seem to find it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this.  The best idea I have is to add a parameter to the report for either "Expanded" or "Collapsed".  Then, in the report, set the InitialToggleState of the report items to be an expression involving that parameter.  Then, the user can choose whether they want the report fully expanded or collapsed upon initial load.

Comment: That is the only way i have found to do it as well